# Public DNS for a domain on Route 53 and would like to use Azure Private DNS for internal resolution

Tags: domain-name-system, azure, amazon-route53, split-dns

We are in the process of migrating on premises / datacenter service from colocation to Microsoft Azure. We have several domains, let's call one myapp.com. The myapp.com web server is available to the world and public DNS for this domain is handled on Route 53.

In our Microsoft Azure VNET where the myapp.com server sits, we have created a private Azure DNS zone for myapp.com and configured the VNET to use it. This is so we can put internal host names here - e.g. sql.myapp.com, test-host.myapp.com, etc there for resolution that points to internal myapp.com resources.

As soon as we create the private DNS zone in Azure and link the VNET, none of the public entries are available as the Azure DNS private zone is authoritative.

**My query: Is there any way to use Azure private DNS and Route53 public DNS for the same domain without maintaining the entire zone file in 2 places?**

In the colocated environment we used a local server with DNSMASQ as the internal DNS which can just use its hosts file as a resolver and anything unresolved was forwarded to public DNS. This was really easy as it wasn't an authoritative resolver and only contained the internal hosts.

Apparently some Azure service work a lot better if you use Azure DNS - e.g. application Gateway, so we are looking to use it.

Thanks in advanced for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to setup a self hosted DNS server with conditional forwarders.
For example a docker image on Ubuntu who runs unbound where you have a forwarder zone for you internal domain and the rest to AWS.
But I don't understand why you use route53 in Azure, Azure dns is perfectly capable of public resolving.

You might need to to create a S2S vpn to be able to resolve using route53 from azure

---

There is also this container image https://github.com/whiteducksoftware/az-dns-forwarder/blob/master/README.md You’ll need to configure an outbound route 53 resolver in aws.

Within azure you will need inbound resolvers configuring.

Then in AWS create route 53 rules for domains you wish to forward to azure to the corresponding inbound resolvers setup in azure.

This will allow you to resolve internal azure dns zones.

Comment: Thanks. We customarily separated our external DNS provider from our infrastructure to allow control of customer traffic via DNS should the server centre become unavailable for any length of time. (e.g. failover to an alternative server centre) We have been using Route53 for public DNS since it was introduced as it was comfortably separate from our servers.
Understandably, this is no longer a large concern so perhaps we should move external resolution to Azure as well and be done with it.

Comment: Yeah mixing two cloud providers is not an architectural best practice and makes it only more difficult

Comment: There is also this container https://github.com/whiteducksoftware/az-dns-forwarder/blob/master/README.md. You can use that maybe in route 53 over a vpn